# What .Net framework can i expect to be installed in Windows Comnpact7

Tags: windows, operating-system, .net-framework-version

I have a hard time finding some documentation on what .Net framework is included in an Windows Compact 7 Operating system.

Is there anyway to run .Net Core, or .Net Framework minumum 4.5 on that operating system?